# Looping a rotation into Excel cells

Tags: vba, excel, loops

I have a database of users (with a number assignment) and an Excel listing of items that I am successfully pulling into two arrays.  One array of users, the other of items from Excel (tasks).  I am trying to think of the logic to represent this scenario:

A user in the DB can exist with a number 0-5.  Basically this represents how many days off they are in the week, and help break up how many items in the Excel range each person can get so as to proportion correctly items (before I was using a Boolean indicator to indicate to either include or exclude).  For example:

```
User   |  Present #
-------------------
Jared  |  0 'present daily
John   |  0 'present daily
Mary   |  1 'off 1 day
Tom    |  5 'off rotation entirely
```

Question is: what is the best way to relate this to how many items they should be getting overall?

I would expect `Jared` and `John` to get the most, `Mary` a bit less, and `Tom` would never be included.  Let's say I have 50 items.

One way I have thought is, while looping the names into Excel, count each time I start back at the top of the array as a "pass" (while assigning into Excel cells).

```
    Anyone with a 0 is never skipped through each pass
    Anyone with a 1 is skipped every 4th pass
    Anyone with a 2 is skipped every 3rd pass
    Anyone with a 3 is skipped every 2nd pass
    Anyone with a 4 is skipped every other pass
    Anyone with a 5 is never included (easy)
```

For my example, `Jared` and `John` would always be used, `Mary` would be skipped every fourth pass, and `Tom` would never be used.

Does this make sense?
What is the best way to catch looping through an array every Nth time?
Am I going about this in the correct manner?

Comment: can you re-explain how you got to: "5>15, 5>15, 4>12"?  I understand about taking the reverse, and dividing.

Comment: If you only have 5 numbers, then I would use nested `IF`s or a `Select Case`.  Then just loop with a counter and reset or exit when the counter reaches the amount of tasks.  A `While` loop would be effective here.  Then use a 2D array with like (User, Loop#) and subtract from Loop# each pass.  If Loop# = 0 then add a task and reset Loop# to the user's number.

Comment: @pnuts would you like to offer your comment as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To avoid a lot of looping and the delays this might cause, I’d suggest calculating a ‘demand factor’.
There are 50 items (in the example) to be distributed according to availabilities. The availabilities are shown as `0`  present daily to `5` off rotation entirely, but it is easier to work with these the other way around: ‘off rotation’ has no resources available so `0` and ‘presently daily’ has all weekdays (?) available, so `5`.

The User | Present # table would then become:

```
 
Jared   5
John    5
Mary    4
Tom     0
      14
```

So 14 person-days are available to cover 50 items, an average of 3.57 items per person-day. Presuming an item can’t be split that is 3 items per person-day and 8 over. The ‘3 each’ can be allocated in one pass by multiplying the (revised) table values by INT(item_total/table-total). So for Jared and John the result is 5x3 = 15 and for Mary 4x3 = 12.

That though only accounts for 42, so 8 have yet to be allocated. 3,3,2 ‘extras’ is obvious (resulting in 18,18,14) but programming that not so easy. I’d suggest where there is any residual from the INT formula then use its result +1 (ie here 4 rather than 3) accept preliminary results of 20,20,16,0 (6 too many) then loop through each user knocking 1 off (where possible) until 6 have been knocked off.

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't entirely make sense since you appear to be assigning weekly tasks, one per day:

> Anyone with a 0 is never skipped through each pass
>
> Anyone with a 1 is skipped every 4th pass
>
> Anyone with a 2 is skipped every 3rd pass
>
> Anyone with a 3 is skipped every 2nd pass
>
> Anyone with a 4 is skipped every other pass
>
> Anyone with a 5 is never included (easy)

However, presuming the above, you skip users when their individual `TaskAssignmentsAttempted Mod (6 - Present#) = 0`.

Perhaps you need:

> Anyone with a 0 is never skipped
>
> Anyone with a 1 is skipped once every 5 passes
>
> Anyone with a 2 is skipped twice every 5 passes
>
> Anyone with a 3 is skipped 3 times every 5 passes
>
> Anyone with a 4 is skipped 4 times every 5 passes
>
> Anyone with a 5 is always skipped.

Presuming the above, you skip users when their individual `5 - Present#` is less than their individual `TaskAssignmentsAttempted Mod 5`.

With either of these, you need to track the number of times that each user has an assignment attempt (successful or not), as well as the actual assignments.